# Understanding this terrain intersection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, terrain, intersection, quadtree

I was looking for a fast way to get a ray intersection point of a terrain defined by a heightmap and I stumbled upon this: https://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/250170/250170.pdf

At part 3.2, I don't quite understand why we would get an intersection point in the beginning of the while loop, since it starts with the first quadtree node which is basically the whole map. Thus, there shouldn't be an intersection point with the ray (except if the ray starts out of AABB, higher than the max height of the terrain but that is never the case for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There shouldn't be an intersection point with the ray (except if the ray starts out of AABB, higher than the max height of the terrain but that is never the case for me).

It sounds like you're using "intersection point" here to mean "a point where the ray *enters* the AABB from *outside* the AABB volume".

But the paper uses a different definition of intersection, described on page 4:

> ...efficient ray-AABB intersection is possible by utilizing the slab method. With this method, the AABB
> is conceptually surrounded by pairs of parallel planes and the ray is clipped against each pair (see
> Figure 2.3). If any portion of the ray still exists after clipping, the ray intersected the AABB.

So here they're really talking about an "intersection *span*" - a *segment* of the ray that is contained inside the AABB volume.

A ray that starts inside the AABB enclosing your whole terrain will always have a span intersecting the volume in this way, even if it lacks an entry point, because the span from its origin to its exit point will remain after the clipping operation described above.

A ray with no span intersecting the AABB is one that misses the AABB entirely - in these cases it is safe to not subdivide the node to check for intersections with its children, because we know there will be none.

So, this means we continue iterating the loop and splitting nodes as long as there is a potential intersection to find, and stop only when further intersections with the terrain are impossible, because the ray has no overlap at all with the other bounding boxes.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: By reading more forward in the PDF, at section 3.4 the author talks about an algorithm (named: **Algorithm for computer control of a digital plotter
by J. E. Bresenham**) that can tell which heightmap element is the ray on. It came to my mind why can't we just use this thing for the entire map then? It seems easier and faster to just get the ray and check for intersection with the plotted triangles instead of keep dividing the map into quads. Maybe do you have a theory for this?

Comment: It's just a question of how many cells you want to examine. Imagine you have a 2k x 2k heightmap with a mountain in the north-east corner, and a flat plain around. You fire a ray toward the mountain from eye height above the plain at the south-west corner. Do you want to iterate over all 2000 cells of the diagonal with Bresenham's algorithm? Or do you want to quickly reject three quarters of the map using the quadtree, and search only the cells close to the actual mountain?